# Using Flask-SQLAlchemy in Blueprint models without reference to the app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a "modular application" in Flask using Blueprints.

When creating models, however, I'm running into the problem of having to reference the app in order to get the `db`-object provided by Flask-SQLAlchemy. I'd like to be able to use some blueprints with more than one app (similar to how Django apps can be used), so this is not a good solution.*

- It's possible to do a switcharoo, and have the Blueprint create the `db` instance, which the app then imports together with the rest of the blueprint. But then, any other blueprint wishing to create models need to import from **that** blueprint instead of the app.

My questions are thus:

- Is there a way to let Blueprints define models without any awareness of the app they're being used in later -- and have several Blueprints come together? By this, I mean having to import the app module/package from your Blueprint.
- Am I wrong from the outset? Are Blueprints not meant to be independent of the app and be redistributable (à la Django apps)?

  - If not, then what pattern *should* you use to create something like that? Flask extensions? Should you simply not do it -- and maybe centralize all models/schemas à la Ruby on Rails?

> *Edit*: I've been thinking about this myself now, and this might be more related to SQLAlchemy than Flask because you have to have the `declarative_base()` when declaring models. And *that's* got to come from somewhere, anyway!
>
> Perhaps the best solution is to have your project's schema defined in one place and spread it around, like Ruby on Rails does. Declarative SQLAlchemy class definitions are really more like schema.rb than Django's models.py. I imagine this would also make it easier to use migrations (from [alembic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/alembic/) or [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/)).

---

I was asked to provide an example, so let's do something simple: Say I have a blueprint describing "flatpages" -- simple, "static" content stored in the database. It uses a table with just shortname (for URLs), a title and a body. This is `simple_pages/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from .models import Page

flat_pages = Blueprint('flat_pages', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@flat_pages.route('/<page>')
def show(page):
    page_object = Page.query.filter_by(name=page).first()
    return render_template('pages/{}.html'.format(page), page=page_object)
```

Then, it would be nice to let this blueprint define its own model (this in `simple_page/models.py`):

```
# TODO Somehow get ahold of a `db` instance without referencing the app
# I might get used in!

class Page(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    content = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __init__(self, name, title, content):
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
```

---

This question is related to:

- [Flask-SQLAlchemy import/context issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692962/flask-sqlalchemy-import-context-issue)
- [What's your folder layout for a Flask app divided in modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089020/whats-your-folder-layout-for-a-flask-app-divided-in-modules?rq=1)

And various others, but all replies seem to rely on import the app's `db` instance, or doing the reverse. The ["Large app how to"](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/wiki/Large-app-how-to) wiki page also uses the "import your app in your blueprint" pattern.

<sub>* Since the official documentation shows how to create routes, views, templates and assets in a Blueprint without caring about what app it's "in", I've assumed that Blueprints should, in general, be reusable across apps. However, this modularity doesn't seem *that* useful without also having independent models.</sub>

<sub>Since Blueprints can be hooked into an app more than once, it might simply be the wrong approach to have models in Blueprints?</sub>

Comment: Do the blueprints you are creating as plugable apps *need* to define the models that they use?  Or can they simply be *given* models from the application?  If the former, could you give an example of a type of re-usable blueprint that you are trying to create that needs to define its own models?

Comment: I provided a simple example, like you asked. It's hard to speak about "need" in this context: It doesn't "need" to define its own models if that's the fundamentally wrong way to approach it, but I was under the impression that's how you "should" do it. However, I can understand if Flask is better used like RoR where the schema is defined in your app, and "provided" to various plugins. I guess in that case, you'd use configuration to provide that?

Comment: Why [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9695045/114833) doesn't work in your case? It doesn't reference app in model or blueprint module.

Comment: It still relies on a shared namespace, `shared.apps`, which makes it hard to use the same blueprint across apps (where there might not be any agreement on such a namespace)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I believe the truest answer is that modular blueprints shouldn't concern themselves directly with data access, but instead rely on the application providing a compatible implementation.

So given your example blueprint.

```
from flask import current_app, Blueprint, render_template

flat_pages = Blueprint('flat_pages', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@flat_pages.record
def record(state):
    db = state.app.config.get("flat_pages.db")

    if db is None:
        raise Exception("This blueprint expects you to provide "
                        "database access through flat_pages.db")

@flat_pages.route('/<page>')
def show(page):
    db = current_app.config["flat_pages.db"]
    page_object = db.find_page_by_name(page)
    return render_template('pages/{}.html'.format(page), page=page_object)
```

From this, there is nothing preventing you from providing a default implementation.

```
def setup_default_flat_pages_db(db):
    class Page(db.Model):
        name = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
        title = db.Column(db.String(255))
        content = db.Column(db.String(255))

        def __init__(self, name, title, content):
            self.name = name
            self.title = title
            self.content = content

    class FlatPagesDBO(object):
        def find_page_by_name(self, name):
            return Page.query.filter_by(name=name).first()

    return FlatPagesDBO()
```

And in your configuration.

```
app.config["flat_pages.db"] = setup_default_flat_pages_db(db)
```

The above could be made cleaner by not relying in direct inheritance from db.Model and instead just use a vanilla declarative_base from sqlalchemy, but this should represent the gist of it.

Comment: Very interesting take! I don't know if this is how you "should do it" but since there doesn't seem to be one true way to solve the problem, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: The answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695045/6421681 should be considered along with this one. This other answer doesn't require importing `app`, but it does require importing `db`; however, there's a clever workaround in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

I have similar needs of making Blueprints completely modular and having no reference to the App. I came up with a possibly clean solution but I'm not sure how correct it is and what its limitations are.

The idea is to create a separate `db` object (`db = SQLAlchemy()`) inside the blueprint and call the `init_app()` and `create_all()` methods from where the root app is created.

Here's some sample code to show how the project is structured:
The app is called `jobs` and the blueprint is called `status` and it is stored inside the blueprints folder.

`blueprints.status.models.py`

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()  # <--- The db object belonging to the blueprint

class Status(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'status'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    job_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    status = db.Column(db.String(120))
```

`models.py`

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()  # <--- The db object belonging to the root app

class Job(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'job'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    state = db.Column(db.String(120)
```

`factory.py`

```
from .blueprints.status.models import db as status_db  # blueprint db
from .blueprints.status.routes import status_handler   # blueprint handler
from .models import db as root_db                      # root db
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Create database resources.
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////path/to/app.db'
    root_db.init_app(app)
    status_db.init_app(app)     # <--- Init blueprint db object.
    with app.app_context():
        root_db.create_all()
        status_db.create_all()  # <--- Create blueprint db.

    # Register blueprint routes.
    app.register_blueprint(status_handler, url_prefix="/status")

    return app
```

I tested it with `gunicorn` with `gevent` worker and it works. I asked a separate question about the robustness of the solution here:
[Create one SQLAlchemy instance per blueprint and call create_all multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963461/create-one-sqlalchemy-instance-per-blueprint-and-call-create-all-multiple-times)

Comment: Since your separate question was removed do you have anything additional to add now?

Comment: Check out this documentation (CTRL + F "But, rather, in model.py (or equivalent)"):
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/appfactories/
And you can find, that solution from this answer is right there.

Answer (score 0):

You asked "Are Blueprints not meant to be independent of the app and be redistributable (à la Django apps)? "

The answer is yes. Blueprints are not similar to Django App.

If you want to use different app/configurations, then you need to use "Application Dispatching" and not blueprints. Read this 
  [1]: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/#app-dispatch [1]

Also, the link here [1] http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/#the-concept-of-blueprints [1]

It clearly says and I quote "A blueprint in Flask is not a pluggable app because it is not actually an application – it’s a set of operations which can be registered on an application, even multiple times. Why not have multiple application objects? You can do that (see Application Dispatching), but your applications will have separate configs and will be managed at the WSGI layer."

Comment: Right, I appreciate that they are not exactly like Django apps. But this description does not, to me, say that they are neither *independent* nor *redistributable*. It seems to me that Blueprints *are* meant to (in general) be registrable on more than one application. A Django app isn't really like a Flask app either -- it doesn't come with its own configuration or WSGI separation.