# Cant import mysql instance from another module python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

There is following structure:

`-app.py 
--blueprints/feed.py`

at the app.py i has

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="app/templates")
mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'dt-products'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
app.register_blueprint(feed)
```

and now at feed.py module im trying to import mysql like that:

`from app import mysql`
but it doesnt works. where i did mistake ?

thanks.

Comment: Include the traceback in the question you are getting

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058800/using-flask-sqlalchemy-in-blueprint-models-without-reference-to-the-app

Comment: from app import mysql
ImportError: cannot import name mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from ..app import mysql
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: is there some way to get access to index file like from ./app ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that i had same name of app folder and app module, thats was a reason of importing issue.